# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f995be07650

Tags: ios, swift, timer, unrecognized-selector

I have latest updated Xcode .i just started learning swift and i'm getting error. Please Help. Thanks

```
2018-07-31 06:30:29.085754+1200 swift4[2874:61277] -[swift4.ViewController uda1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe13f6122a0
2018-07-31 06:30:29.089728+1200 swift4[2874:61277] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[swift4.ViewController uda1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe13f6122a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102dfd1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102492031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e7e784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001034a86db -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d7f898 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d7f278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   Foundation                          0x0000000101efc4dd __NSFireTimer + 83
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d8ce64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d8ca52 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d8c60a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d83e4c __CFRunLoopRun + 2252
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d8330b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001089d1a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010327a057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    14  swift4                              0x0000000101b86927 main + 55
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010720d955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm getting error:

In my Viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer1 = Timer()
    var  counter  = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Start(_ sender: Any) {
        counter = 0
        Label.text = String (counter)

        timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: ("uda1") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
    }

    func uda1 ()
    {
        counter += 1
        Label.text = String(counter)
    }

    @IBAction func Stop(_ sender: Any) {
        timer1.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - variable and function names should start with lowercase letters. And you do not need `;` in Swift.

Comment: Because your selector format is not proper(it should be #selector(uda1)) and selector method definition should start from @objc

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, #selector(uda1) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
```

//

```
@objc func uda1()
{
    counter += 1
    Label.text = String(counter)

}
```

//

```
var timer1:Timer?
```

//

```
timer1?.invalidate()
```